# How do I setup pagination with express serving static json file?

Tags: node.js, express

I am serving a {huge} static json file using express as below which is consumed by an angular front end.  Currently it takes about 5 minutes before I can see data in the browser. Is it possible serve this file in chunks (it has an id key) simulating pagination?

express

```
...
    ReportRouter.route('/list')
        .get(function(req, res){
            //res.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            fs.readFile('./file.json','utf8',function(err,data){
                if(err) throw err;
                res.json(JSON.parse(data));
            });
        });
...
```

Comment: If you can accomodate something like that client-side, would it be an option to split the file into multiple separate JSON files on the server and have the client pass a counter as to which file should be retrieved? `/list?page=23` would retrieve `./file.23.json`, for instance.

Comment: Hey @Bala, did you find and efficient solution for this?